# View pass only first value MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need some help with my project.
Its my ViewModel:

```
public class ServiceView
{
    public IList<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public Actionresult Swap()
{
    var services = from proj in db.Service select proj;
            ServiceView model = new ServiceView();
            model.Services = services.ToList();
            return View(model);
}
```

View where displays services:

```
@model proj.Models.ServiceView
@using(Html.BeginForm("SelectServices" , "AdditionalServices"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count; i++)
    {
        <td>Name: @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Services[i].Name) </td>
        <td>Price:@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Services[i].Price)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Services[i].Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Services[i].Price)
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
        </td>
    }
}
```

Post - Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectServices(ServiceView serviceView)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < serviceView.Services.Count; i++)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Pool", "Rank",
            new
            {
            serviceName = serviceView.Services[i].Name,
            servicePrice = serviceView.Services[i].Price,
    });
}
```

In `serviceName = serviceView.Services[i].Name`I have only first element always.Why? what is my fault?

Comment: Calling `return RedirectToAction()` immediately exits the method and redirects. What is it you are actually trying to do? You have a form whih can't even be edited!

Comment: I want pass this parameters to another Controller , and HttpPost should have only RedirectToAction

Comment: But what is the point of this. You have a form that cant be edited (only hidden controls) . Since your controller sent the collection to the view, what is the point of sending it back unchanged except to degrade your application (just get the collection again the way you did initially in the GET method). And you cant pass a collection to a GET method anyway so it hard to understand what your trying to actually achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do some work to help model binder make the collection. Use the following syntax in your view to make hidden fields.

```
    @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].Name", Model.Services[i].Name)
    @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].Price", Model.Services[i].Price)
```

Then in your post action method you need to receive the collection

```
public ActionResult SelectServices(IList<Services> services)
{
   foreach(var sv in services)
    {
                    return RedirectToAction("Pool", "Rank",
                        new
                        {
                        serviceName = sv.Name,
                        servicePrice = sv.Price,
                        });
     }

}
```

Comment: OP is already creating the correct name attributes for posting back to the model! You need to read the question again.

Comment: He want to receive the collection and unless he help the model binder by naming the hidden field as i mentioned, Model binder can not make the collection.

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through some basic tutorials. The model **is** being being bound correctly. And your dreadful hack means that `ModelState` will be ignored.

Comment: You need a walk through of model binding process. Have you ever did a model binding for collections of custom types? Go and get some help. You might know the basics but this is a bit advance for you. Not everything will be done by the framework automatically for you.

Comment: OMG. Try OP's code. IT WORKS AND IS CORRECTLY BOUND. Read OP's code carefully. Look at the first line in the `if` block - the `return` statement! That means the `SelectServices()` method exits the method (so only one iteration of the loop is ever executed)