# Access element of ilist MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ilist

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IList<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Car
{
    int id { get; set };
    string Color { get; set };
}
```

Post Action:

```
public ActionResult Select(ViewModel model)
{
    foreach(var car in model.Cars) 
    {
        carId = car.Id;
        // more code...
    }
    return RedirectToAction("one","two",new { carId });
}
```

How to access for this element? Is this right?

Comment: This seems to be related to this [equally ridiculous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335905/pass-ilist-on-mvc). Show you view and show the method you want to redirect to. Then go back and read my comments to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280700/view-pass-only-first-value-mvc) and edit this question to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`Cars` is a list of `Car` objects, it doesn't have an `Id` property. You need to access items on the list in order to get car's ids

It's hard to know what you specifically want to do. Do you have a single element on the list? Then something like this would do the trick

```
int carId = model.Cars.First().Id;
```

Do you need to iterate over elements in the list. Then you need to use a `foreach` loop

```
int carId = 0;
foreach(var car in model.Cars) 
{
    carId = car.Id;
    // more code...
}
```

If you need to select ALL ids then something like this would do the trick

```
var carsIds = model.Cars.Select(c => c.Id);
```

Comment: I need to pass the elements of the collection Car to use them(for example to display on the next page ) . Please help me. What is wrong

Comment: I need retirect to action with this elements

Comment: @andrey1567: You can use `RedirectToAction` method.

Comment: On the next page I need display: "You select Ford"

Comment: Yes I have redirectToAction, but I dont know how pass element from ilist

Comment: @andrey1567: `RedirectToAction("YourActionName", object-you-want-to-pass);`

Comment: @andrey1567: that's not correct. You have to use `var carsIds = model.Cars.Select(c => c.Id);` and send all ids in one shoot.

Comment: but how I display selected element?  In controller  I write: ActionResult(int carsIds){@Viewbag.Message = carsIds} And In View I need display this information.But did not work((